# Get select list option elements by value(s)

Tags: jquery, html-select

I need to move certain `<option>` elements from one `<select>` list to the other - and perhaps back and forth as well - so it can't rely on hard-coded data and I need to target the `<option>` elements I want to move via their `value` attribute.

So say I have this html:

```
<option value="1">cat #1</option>
<option value="2">cat #2</option>
<option value="3">cat #3</option>
<option value="4">cat #4</option>
<option value="5">cat #5</option>
<option value="6">cat #6</option>
```

Then say I want the elements with the values `3,4,5` how can I do this?

**Edit:** It would be ideal if I could pass the values wanted in as above such as `3,4,5`.

**Edit 2:** These values also need to be removed from the select list they are taken from.

After I get the data back I will be appending it to another select list such as:

```
$(dataVar).appendTo('#selected_cats');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an attribute selector:

```
var selector = dataVar.split(',').map(function(el) {
    return 'option[value='+el.trim()+']';
}).join(',');
$(selector).appendTo('#selected_cats');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/hk24Y/6/)

Comment: The values I get are returned to me in a comma delimited fashion - is there any way to pass the values in like that instead?

Comment: It shouldn't be appending strings, it should be adding options to the other select.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is, the values that I want to get get would be great if I could do something like: `dataVar = $('4,5,6');` to get the correct elements wanted. I know that's not valid code, just trying to show you what I meant. Also, I just noticed your code only *adds* the elements to the new select list, doesn't take/remove them from the first select; sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: I've changed my answer to start with the comma-separated list of values, and updated the fiddle to work with that.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that my answer doesn't remove from the first select list. It does for me.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm just not sure *how* it removes the elements from the first select when there is no reference to it at all.

Comment: A DOM element can only be in one place at a time. So when you append it to the second select, it's removed from the old one as a result.

Comment: Ok, I see the reference now on the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was this..

```
var data_holder = '';

$.each(mr_val, function(index, number) {
    data_holder += '#all_cats option[value="' + number + '"], ';
});        

// Ge rid of last space & comma
data_holder = rtrim(data_holder, ' ,');

// Now remove options from first select and append to the other
var options = $(data_holder).appendTo('#selected_cats');
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong. You need to put `#all_cats` in the `$.each` loop. You're only using that prefix for the first option, not the rest.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure what you mean. The each loop is simply formatting a text string from the passed in value string which holds the values such as `4,5,6`.

Comment: When you concatenate `'#all_cats '` and `data_holder`, the selector looks like `$('#all_cats option[value="1"], option[value="2"], option[value="3"]')`. So the ID is only referenced when selecting `option[value="1"]`, but not the other two.

Comment: It should be: `$('#all_cats option[value="1"], #all_cats option[value="2"], #all_cats option[value="3"]')`

Comment: @Barmar Ohhh... I get what you mean now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...?

```
function moveOptions(sourceList, targetList, movableValues) {
    sourceList.find('option').each(function(){
        if (movableValues.indexOf($(this).val()) > -1) {
            $(this).appendTo(targetList);
        }
    });
}

// Usage:
var pullFrom = $("#list1");
var moveTo = $("#list2");
var moveThese = ['3','4','5'];

moveOptions( pullFrom, moveTo, moveThese );
```